# How to save the Firefox dmg BEFORE updating Mac

Tags: firefox, macbook-pro-retina, dmg-image

I am on a Macbook Pro Retina using High Sierra. When I update Firefox, I would like to save the .dmg BEFORE installing it, just in case the newer version disables some of my tweaks and addons.
I don't want to take the chance of downloading FF from some alternate source after the fact.
I cannot figure out how to do this with the latest updates to Firefox.

Anyone?

Comment: You want to save the Firefox executable or your Firefox user profile, Firefox can easily be redownloaded. Why do you want to save the .dmg?

Comment: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/ here are the old versions of Firefox